# Implementing IOnErrorListener/IOnPreparedListener for MediaPlayer - Xamarin.Android (C#) API 29+

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm new here. This isn't a question, but rather it's a solution since I didn't find a forum answering the concern I had.

I was trying to play an MP3 file as I am downloading it (streaming). To do so I used MediaPlayer.

I read that I should be implementing IOnErrorListener as well as IOnPreparedListener.

Every solution I found about the implementation didn't work out for me.

That is because no one specified **your class needs to inherit from AppCompatActivity.**
If your class does inherit from AppCompatActivity, the implementation should be of only one function. If it doesn't it goes bananas.

Check the following image:

[image: Implentation of IOnPreparedListner with & w/o inheriting from AppCompatActivity]

Here's an example of my working code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Widget;
using System;

namespace Test_MediaPlayerMP3Stream
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, MediaPlayer.IOnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        Button btnPlay;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            btnPlay = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnPlay);
            btnPlay.Click += btnPlay_Click;
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ab = new AudioAttributes.Builder();
            ab.SetContentType(AudioContentType.Speech);
            ab.SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Media);

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.SetOnPreparedListener(this);

            mediaPlayer.SetAudioAttributes(ab.Build());
            mediaPlayer.SetDataSource("YourURL");
            mediaPlayer.PrepareAsync();
        }

        public void OnPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            mp.Start();
        }
        public bool OnError(MediaPlayer mp, [GeneratedEnum] MediaError what, int extra)
        {
            mp.Reset();
            return false;
        }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

    }
}
```

Hopefully, I saved someone some time.

Comment: You shouldn't post answers as questions. Instead, post a question AND an answer to the question.